# How do I test a method was called within a class under test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, nunit, rhino-mocks

I'll start by saying I am pretty new to unit testing and I'd like to start using a TDD approach, but for now am writing unit tests for some existing classes to verify their functionality in all cases.

I've been able to test the majority of my code using NUnit and Rhino mocks without much trouble. However, I've been wondering about unit testing functions that end up calling a lot of other methods within the same class. I can't do something like

```
classUnderTest.AssertWasCalled(cut => cut.SomeMethod(someArgs))
```

because the class under test isn't a fake. Furthermore, if a method I'm testing calls other methods in the class under test that in turn also call methods in the same class, I'm going to need to fake a ton of values just to test the "top level" method. Since I'm also unit testing all of these "sub methods", I should be able to assume that "SomeMethod" works as expected if it passes the unit test and not need to worry about the details of those lower-level methods.

Here is some example code I've been working with to help illustrate my point (I've written a class to manage import/export of Excel files using NPOI):

```
    public DataSet ExportExcelDocToDataSet(bool headerRowProvided)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        for (int i = 0; i < currentWorkbook.NumberOfSheets; i++)
        {               
            ISheet tmpSheet = currentWorkbook.GetSheetAt(i);

            if (tmpSheet.PhysicalNumberOfRows == 0) { continue; }
            DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromExcelSheet(headerRowProvided, ds, tmpSheet);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                AddNonEmptyTableToDataSet(ds, dt);
            }
        }

        return ds;
    }

    public DataTable GetDataTableFromExcelSheet(bool headerRowProvided, DataSet ds, ISheet tmpSheet)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        for (int sheetRowIndex = 0; sheetRowIndex <= tmpSheet.LastRowNum; sheetRowIndex++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = GetDataRowFromExcelRow(dt, tmpSheet, headerRowProvided, sheetRowIndex);
            if (dataRow != null && dataRow.ItemArray.Count<object>(obj => obj != DBNull.Value) > 0)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            }
        }

        return dt;
    }

...
```

You can see that **ExportExcelDocToDataSet** (my "top-level" method in this case) calls **GetDataTableFromExcelSheet** which calls **GetDataRowFromExcelRow**, which calls a couple of other methods that are defined within this same class.

So what is the recommended strategy for refactoring this code to make it more unit testable without having to stub values called by submethods? Is there a way to fake method calls within the class under test?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modify the subject [under test (SUT)](http://xunitpatterns.com/SUT.html). If something is hard to unit test, then the design might be awkward.

Faking method calls within the class under test leads to over specified tests. The result are very brittle tests: As soon as you modify or refactor the class, then it is very likely that you also need modify the unit tests. This leads too high maintenance costs of unit testing.

To avoid over specified tests, concentrate on public methods. If this method calls other methods within the class, do not test these calls. On the other hand: Method calls on other [dependend on component (DOCs)](http://xunitpatterns.com/DOC.html) should be tested.

If you stick to that and have the feeling that you miss some important thing in your tests, then it might be a sign for a class or a method which is doing too much. In case of a class: Look for violations of the [Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Extract classes out of it and test them separately. In case of a method: Split it up the method in several public methods and test each of them separately. If this is still too awkward, you definitely have a class which violates the SRP.

In your specific case you can do the following: Extract the methods `ExportExcelDocToDataSet` and `GetDataTableFromExcelSheet` into two different classes (maybe call them `ExcelToDataSetExporter` and `ExcelSheetToDataTableExporter`). The original class which contained both methods should reference both classes and call those methods, which you previously extracted. Now you are able to test all three classes in isolation. Apply the [Extract Class refactoring](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/extractClass.html) ([book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201485672)) to achieve the modification of your original class.

Also note that retrofitting tests are always a bit cumbersome to write and maintain. The reason is that the SUTs, which are written without unit tests, tend to have an awkward design and thus are harder to test. This means that the problems with unit tests must be solved by modifying the SUTs and cannot be solved by pimping up the unit tests.

Comment: I had thought of extracting the methods you mentioned into separate classes so I could unit test them using the AssertWasCalled extension, but I wasn't sure if this was a great idea because I could see that leading to a ton of very shallow classes with one or two methods in them at most. I will definitely check out the book you recommended and also more about the SRP. The best thing about all of this is I'm the only person on the project and all the code has been written by me, so I can do whatever I need to make it work out.

Comment: @Gage Trader: Do not measure a class in terms of numbers of methods. For example the Command Pattern exposes only one method and still is a widley used technique. Before I applied unit testing and good OO design principles, I was not comfortable with the higher number of classes. I took me some time to realize that a higher number of classes does not mean more work. Yes, it is true that you need more time for design and testing, but the higher quality and the lower bug count compensates this by far.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't really matter what tested method calls under the hood - this is implementation detail and your unit tests shouldn't be *much* aware of that. Usually (well, most of the time with unit testing) you want to test *single unit* and focus on that.

You could either write separate, isolated tests for each public method in your class or refactor part of functionality of your tested class outside. Both approaches focus on same thing though - having isolated tests for each *unit*.

Now, to give you few hints:

- what is the name of your tested class? Basing on methods it exposes, something along the lines of `ExcelExporterAndToDataSetConverter` ... or `ExcelManager`? It seems as this class might be doing [too many things at once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle); this asks for bit of refactoring. Exporting data to DataSet can be easily separated from converting excel data to DataSets/DataRows.
- what happens when `GetDataTableFromExcelSheet` method changes? Gets moved to other class or is replaced by 3rd party code? Should it break your export tests? It shouldn't - this is one of the reasons your export tests shouldn't verify whether it was called or not.

I suggest moving to DataSet/DataRow conversion methods to separate class - it will ease writing of the unit tests and your export tests won't be as fragile.

Comment: Good guess on the name of the class: It is called "ExcelHelper" and the idea is for it to be a singular class called by the rest of my application to deal with anything Excel related. I should probably create at least an ExcelImporter and ExcelExporter class, and after reading these comments I have some ideas for further splitting up the code. I had always thought of refactoring in terms of splitting code up into smaller, private methods in the same class to handle the work rather than write more classes with specific purposes.

Comment: @GageTrader: *helpers*, *managers* and all that vaguely named classes usually indicate SRP violation. `ExcelImporter` communicates its role/purpose very well. What `ExcelHelper` communicates? Helps with what...? Difficulty with class naming is one of the signs of SRP violation - it's harder to find fitting name for class. You should definitely refactor some of your code out - your design will be cleaner, more understandable, and more easily testable.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are testing the public method `GetDataTableFromExcelSheet` separately, so for the tests of `ExportExcelDocToDataSet` you don't need to verify the behaviour of `GetDataTableFromExcelSheet` (beyond the fact that `ExportExcelDocToDataSet` works as expected).

A common strategy is to test only public methods, as any private methods supporting your public methods are tested by default if the public methods behave as expected.

Taking this further, you can test only behaviours of a class, rather than focusing on methods as the unit. That helps to prevent your tests becoming brittle -- where changing the internals of the class has a tendency to break some of your tests.

Of course you want all the code to be well tested, but too tight a focus on methods can lead to brittleness; testing class behaviour (does it do what it should at the highest level) also tests the lower levels.

If you want to fake methods from a test you could refactor your code to take an interface for the method you want to fake. See the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern).

In this case though the obvious change would be for the `ExportExcelDocToDataSet` to take a workbook as an argument. In testing you can then send a fake workbook. See [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: I do have a constructor that takes an IWorkbook object to mock the workbook object (I didn't show any constructors in my example), so that part is taken care of. GetDataTableFromExcelSheet would be private were it not for me wanting to test it. I see what you're saying about testing only the public methods - I had been opening up a lot of my previously private methods for testing due to the complexity of some of the methods at the higher levels. I like your advice a lot because I was spending a lot of time writing tests for every method I had, which probably isn't the right way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing is for sure You are doing TDD the right way :)
Well in the code above you will have to mock the method GetDataTableFromExcelSheet before testing the ExportExcelDocToDataSet method.

But one thing you can do is instead pass the datatable returned from GetDataTableFromExcelSheet from the place in your code where you called ExportExcelDocToDataSet method by adding another parameter.

something like this

DataTable dtExcelData = GetData....;
and modify the method as below

public DataSet ExportExcelDocToDataSet(bool headerRowProvided, DataTable dtExcelData)

This way you will not need to mock GetDataTableFromExcelSheet inside of ExportExcelDocToDataSet method when testing ExportExcelDocToDataSet method.

Comment: Good point about passing the DataTable in instead of just getting the return value. I tend to flip-flop on how best to do that: pass in an instantiated object or return it to the calling method. I still have more dependencies further down the call stack (not shown) though, so I would still have the original problem in regard to not being able to test some of those lower-level methods.